# WPF Expander content section grows but does not shrink

Tags: wpf, resize, wpf-controls, autoresize, expander

I have an Expander that contains an ItemsControl object. Items can be added to the ItemsControl object dynamically by the user and the content area grows to accommodate those items. However, when the items are removed, the content area of the expander (containing the ItemsControl) does not shrink back down.

For example, if I start with one item in the content area of height h, then add two more of the same height, for a total height of 3h, then the content area is ~3h in height. However, when I remove two of the three items, the content area remains at height 3h, rather than reverting to height h.

I have set height and width of the controls to auto and have played around with different margin and padding combinations, but not luck. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You should set Expander width and height to auto with margin of 0 from all sides

Repeat this configuration for all expander content including its items